# Does streambuilder from firebase rtdb will update list<User> user data?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

currently I understadn with the method streamBuilder I can fetch updated data and add in the `List<User> users`.

But what if this user which is already added in the `List<User> users` has updated data, and then it could be double adding this user data in the `List<User> users` right?

1. Could you plz show me how to confirm whether for the new coming data `List<User> users` has already same userId, if yes, the new data / userId will replace this exisiting userId?
2. If the user is deleted from Firebase rtdb, the stream will be notified, and therefore remove this user from `List<User> users`?

here is example, my concern is since stream will always add data to the List users, but what if this user is removed from database or disconnect, how to remove this user from this list?

```
    _streamSubscription = availableUserStream.onValue.listen((snap) {
      if (snap.snapshot.exists && snap.snapshot.value != null) {
        DataSnapshot snapshotData = snap.snapshot;
    
        for (var userSnapshot in snapshotData.children) {
          final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(userSnapshot.value as Map);
    
          List<User> users = [];
    
          User newUser = User.fromJson(data);
    
          users.add(newUser);
          firebaseController.setUsers(users: users);
    
        }
      }
    });
```

So I thought to do a double confirm here if this user is still exisitng in the database:

```
  User getRandomSenderUser({User asReceiverUser}) {
    if (availableSenderUsersList.isNotEmpty) {

      final random = Random();
      var i = random.nextInt(availableSenderUsersList.length);

      User randomUser = availableSenderUsersList[i];

      bool thisRandomUserIsAvailable; //TODO
```

I don't know how to do this check, e.g. if this `randomerUser` is unavailable, so I need to get next randomUser, so it should be a loop? But it will slow down the response speed.

```
       updateSenderUserAvailableStatus(asReceiverUser:asReceiverUser,connectionUser: randomUser);
    
          return randomUser;
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }



thank you!
```

**Update**:

Here is the example code, so now I understand stream will pass user data to `List<User> users`, but in my way there will always be user who is added in this list before, but was already removed from database, my plan is using `while loop` for double confirming to remove unavailable user when getting the randomUser, but it sounds not smart and still waste time I guess....

```
      @override
      void initState() {
        _listenAvailableUsers();
    }

    _listenAvailableUsers() {
        var availableUserStream =
            FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('/waitingList');
    
        _streamSubscription = availableUserStream.onValue.listen((snap) {
          if (snap.snapshot.exists && snap.snapshot.value != null) {
            DataSnapshot snapshotData = snap.snapshot;
    
            for (var userSnapshot in snapshotData.children) {
              final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(userSnapshot.value as Map);
    
              List<User> users = [];
    
              User newUser = User.fromJson(data);
    
              users.add(newUser);
              firebaseController.setUsers(users: users);
    
    
            }
          }
        });
      }
```

Here is the method I though to confirm if the randomUser is still existing in the database:

```
 Future<User> getRandomSenderUser({User asReceiverUser}) async {
    if (availableSenderUsersList.isNotEmpty) {

      User randomUser;

      while (true) {
        final random = Random();
        var i = random.nextInt(availableSenderUsersList.length);

        randomUser = availableSenderUsersList[i];

        DatabaseEvent event = await databaseReference
            .child('/waitingList/${randomUser.userId}')
            .once();
        print('randomUser is ${randomUser.toString()}');
        if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
          break;
        }
      }

      await updateSenderUserAvailableStatus(
          asReceiverUser: asReceiverUser, connectionUser: randomUser);

      print('connectionUserId is $connectionUserId');
      return randomUser;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How is `availableUserStream` initialized?

Comment: Hi Frank, please check my update, thank you:)

Comment: I wrote an answer about how `onValue` works below. I'm having a hard time understanding the actual problem though, so if my answer doesn't help you solve it, please edit your question to explain what doesn't work about the code in the line you marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're listening to the `onValue` of a path in the database, the `DataSnapshot` you get will contain the entire data at that path. When there was only a small change in the data, the server will only send that update to the client, but the SDK will then merge that with the existing data and still fire an event with a snapshot of all the data at the path.

Since you're starting with an empty list (`List<User> users = [];`) each time you get an event from the stream, that means you're rebuilding the entire lit of users each time, which seems correct to me.

Comment: dear Frank, you are right, I understadn firebase in a wrong way, and checked it indeeds each time stream will rebuild entire list:)